# dbExpress error in Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, dbexpress

I have had Delphi 2007 for a while.  I tried the Delphi 2009 trial.  Then I un-installed the trial.  Now I get this in a dbExpress Delphi 2007 application:

```
---------------------------
Debugger Exception Notification
---------------------------
Project ABC.exe raised exception class TDBXError with message 
'Unable to load dbxora.dll (ErrorCode 126).  It may be missing
from the system path.'.
---------------------------
Break   Continue   Help   
---------------------------
```

I do not have dbxora.dll anywhere on my pc; I have dbxora30.dll, instead.  Looking at another development machine (which has never had Delphi 2009 on it), I see dbxora30.dll too.  FWIW, that file is here:

```
C:\Program Files\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\bin\dbxora30.dll
```

And my path **does** include this location.

So it looks like Delphi 2009 introduced a new "dbxora.dll" which replaced "dbxora30.dll"... and when I un-installed Delphi 2009, it failed to point my system back to the original "dbxora30.dll".  But now how do I use dbxora30 again?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem on my machine by editing this file:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\dbExpress\dbxdrivers.ini
```

Under the section labeled [Oracle], I changed the "LibraryName" parameter from "dbxora.dll" to "dbxora30.dll".

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty much the same problem, though I installed the full Delphi 2009 along with the existing Delphi 2007 and found that it broke my previous exe files. I uninstalled Delpi 2009 but had to fix it by editing the same file (though it was in a different directory on my machine: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\RAD Studio\dbExpress\dbxdrivers.ini). However, there were more lines than just the one that is mentioned above. Luckily, I had a backup of the ini file from before the Delphi 2009 installation. Here are the two sections in case anybody needs help with this:

```
[Oracle] - FROM DELPHI 2007
DriverUnit=DBXDynalink
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DBXDynalinkDriver100.bpl
DriverPackage=DBXCommonDriver110.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxDynalinkDriver,Version=11.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
DriverAssembly=Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=11.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=a91a7c5705831a4f

GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverORACLE
LibraryName=dbxora30.dll
VendorLib=oci.dll
DataBase=Database Name
User_Name=user
Password=password
BlobSize=-1
ErrorResourceFile=
LocaleCode=0000
Oracle TransIsolation=ReadCommited
RowsetSize=20
OS Authentication=False
Multiple Transaction=False
Trim Char=False
Decimal Separator=.
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXOracleMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxReadOnlyMetaData100.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXOracleMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxReadOnlyMetaData,Version=11.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
```

.

```
[Oracle] - FROM DELPHI 2009
DriverUnit=DBXOracle
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DBXCommonDriver120.bpl
DriverPackage=DBXCommonDriver110.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
DriverAssembly=Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=11.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=a91a7c5705831a4f

GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverORACLE
LibraryName=dbxora.dll
VendorLib=oci.dll
DataBase=Database Name
User_Name=user
Password=password
BlobSize=-1
ErrorResourceFile=
LocaleCode=0000
Oracle TransIsolation=ReadCommited
RowsetSize=20
OS Authentication=False
Multiple Transaction=False
Trim Char=False
Decimal Separator=.
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXOracleMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxOracleDriver120.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXOracleMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxOracleDriver,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
```